# rails : How to query based on acts_as_taggable_on tags of association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

You can find tagged objects using `tagged_with`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags, :skills
  scope :by_join_date, order("created_at DESC")
end

User.tagged_with("awesome").by_join_date
```

But how do you find the associations of tagged objects?

```
class UserAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

UserAccount.joins(:user)...???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserAccount.joins(:user).merge(User.tagged_with("awesome"))`

Or you can use reverse query:

`User.tagged_with("awesome").includes(:user_account).`

Query selection depends on your goal.